# Short story with similar premise to Asimov's Feeling of Power, but with a Janitor who discovers computing using long division

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In Asimov's short story [A Feeling of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feeling_of_Power) knowledge of even simple arithmetic has been lost because everything is run by computers. Earth is at war with Deneb but because both sides use identical computers a stalemate has resulted, and the stalemate is broken when a scientist rediscovers arithmetic and humans can start controlling the war.

The story I am trying to find is very similar, but it is a humble janitor who rediscovers arithmetic, and in the story it is specifically [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) that they rediscover.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and answer as many questions as you can there, editing them into your question. It will help us help you.

Comment: This would also be greatly helped by explaining the premise rather than comparing it.  Even though I have almost certainly read Asimov's *Feeling of Power*, I have no recollection of it.

Comment: Hi Keith. I've expanded your question in an attempt to get it reopened. If my edit isn't appropriate please feel free to roll it back.