# Short story about a man who rediscovers long-division. Not "Feeling of Power"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about a guy who rediscovers how to do long division on paper and is hailed as a genius or oddity, don’t recall which. Everyone is amazed because they’ve used electronic calculators so long they have forgotten the talent of long hand division.

(It’s not Asimov’s 'The Feeling of Power').

Comment: Are you **certain** it's not "The Feeling of Power"? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104167/short-story-people-rediscover-how-to-do-math-and-want-to-put-people-in-bombs

Comment: Could this be the same story? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177749/short-story-with-similar-premise-to-asimovs-feeling-of-power-but-with-a-janito (Unsolved, but with a bit more info).

Comment: How old is the story? When did you read it? Was it in a magazine or book or online?

Answer (score 1):

I remember the story. Earth is at war with another planet, and the military finds a man that can do long division on paper rather than use a "pocket computer". They start speculating about how this will give them the edge in the war. I don't remember much else, except that the story was contained in a book of sci-fi shorts (or maybe just an elementary school reader). The name of the story was "Long Division"

Been trying to find it for decades.

Comment: The story you describe IS "The Feeling of Power."